# Microsoft Graph - Get excel table row by index returns 400 API not found

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graphs to interact with the Excel worksheet in Sharepoint from my Python application using the requests. Whenever I want to access the workbook and its rows as a bunch, everything works, but as soon as I want to use rows indexing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerow-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I got the 400 API not found.

I am working with the following query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet_id}/tables/{table_id}/rows`.

Now, if I follow the documentation, I just append the index to the URL above, yet triggering that GET requests always gets me 400 API not found. The test excel is non-empty and the table and worksheet exist.

Does anyone know what to do about it or it is just not developed yet? If so, why it is not mentioned in the docs then? Thank you all for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue on my side. Probably there are some undocumented changes in the API

As an alternative you can use [itemAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerowcollection-itemat?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint (`/rows/itemAt(index={index}`)

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet_id}/tables/{table_id}/rows/itemAt(index=0)
```

Comment: I have already done it, yet it seems like an error at the Microsoft end IMHO that the standard way is not working.